# character_result_set is empty in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf-8

I'm using mysql DB. The DB is amazone RDS DB.

When I execute this query: `show global variables like '%character%';`
I get the following result:
[image]

But when I execute this query: `show variables like '%character%';` I get this result:
[image]

As you can see character_set_results is empty. I tried following queries and nothing changes the empty value:

```
ALTER DATABASE myDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER DATABASE myDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER DATABASE myDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=UTF8
SET  NAMES 'utf8';
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
SET session CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = utf8;
```

As I understand the second query returns session parameters. Might this affect the results I'm getting?

I have two machines. Development machine where I run the application with eclipse (this is a java app with hibernate) and another one, the deployment machine. Everything works fine on the development machine but on the deployment machine sometimes I'm getting ???? or other strange characters when getting data from DB.
Both machines connect to the same DB and data is stored fine in the db itself.
Also the connection url is `jdbc:mysql://myDB:3306/myApp?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8`.

Any ideas what can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple question marks usually come from:

- You are `INSERTing` Chinese (or any non-western-Europe text).
- You said `SET NAMES utf8` to declare that the client bytes are utf8-encoded (correct).
- But the table columns are declared `CHARSET latin1`.  <-- This is the problem.
- Since there is no way to convert Chinese characters into latin1, '?' stored.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to confirm the above hypothesis.

If you are getting "other strange characters", please provide:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...
```

to show an example of what is stored for the "strange characters".